# How to stop while loop

Tags: java, loops

I have created this While loop to read lines from a text file. How to I stop the loop after it has found the values?

```
     try
    {
       BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Inventory.txt"));
       while (file.ready())
       {
          String ID = file.readLine();
          String Name = file.readLine();
          String Price = file.readLine();

          if (Value.equals(tf_ID.getText()))
          {
             System.out.println(Name +"  "+ Price);
          }
       }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
       System.out.println("Error");
    }
 }
```

Comment: what is your programming language? PHP has a `break` command in the loop which can jump out and continue execution

Comment: @user2838611 do you know google?

Answer (score 2):

Use keyword break, here is link with reference to branching in java:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `break;` in your if statement, it will cause the while loop to stop.

```
if (Value.equals(tf_ID.getText()))
{
    System.out.println(Name +"  "+ Price);
    break;//your while loop will stop
}
```